# Define a relative path in Python

Tags: python, webdav, nextcloud

I have created a program with the following path (for example, KEYS_FILE_PATH), which is a hard-coded absolute path.

KEYS_FILE_PATH = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\encryption_keys.txt'

I would like to define a relative path so that the paths also work under operating systems other than Windows.
i tried this one :

```
current_directory = os.getcwd()
relative_path = "path/to/your/encryption_keys.txt"
```

but it doesn't work
How can I do this with another library ?

Comment: Your script shouldn't assume that it's run from a directory that contains your file. Instead of a hard-coded absolute path, have your script read a path prefix (from an environment variable, a command-line argument, etc.) and append your hard-coded  relative path to *that*.

Comment: (You can *default* to `os.getcwd()` if no argument is given or the environment variable isn't set, but let the user tell you where to look.)